# C++ constexpr function to checksum an array

Tags: c++, arrays, constexpr

Is there away to achieve the behavior shown in the example (non compiling) code below?  I (think I) understand why it doesn't compile given that the required calls to std::initializer_list functions are not constexpr.

The goal is to be able to create an array from a constant initialiser list when an additional element is appended to the end that is the sum of the preceeding elements.

All the posts I found on initialising arrays at compile time required lots of complex recursive template function calls and all were related to generating sequences of numbers.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <array>

template <typename T> constexpr auto CheckSummedArray(const std::initializer_list<T> & i)
{
    std::array<T, i.size() + 1> res;
    std::copy(i.begin(), i.end(), res.begin());
    auto cs = T();
    for (auto r : i)
    {
        cs += r;
    }
    res[res.size() - 1] = cs;
    return res;
}

constexpr auto testArray = CheckSummedArray<int>({1,2,3,4});

static_assert(testArray.size() == 5);
static_assert(testArray[0] == 1);
static_assert(testArray[4] == 9);
```

Comment: What's your compiler version? What's the compile option `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17` you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the calls to the members of `std::initializer_list`, those functions are actually constexpr. The issue is that you are using the result of `i.size()` in a template parameter, but `i` is not a constant expression, since it's a function parameter.

You can solve this by making the argument an array type, and so you can deduce its size with a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N> 
constexpr auto CheckSummedArray(T const(&i)[N])
{
    std::array<T, N + 1> res{};
    std::copy(i, i + N, res.begin());
    res.back() = std::accumulate(i, i + N, 0);
    return res;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s88cxqebW).

I cleaned up the function a little by using an algorithm instead of a loop. If you're not using C++20, you don't have access to constexpr algorithms, so your `copy` and `accumulate` will need to be raw loops anyway.

```
for(std::size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
{    
    res[j] = i[j];
    res.back() += i[j];
}
```

Here's a [C++17 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cEbavrfsc).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, it was exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately I cant use C++20 in this project, only C++17.

Actually, the assert is correct, the code itself is incorrect.  There should be a -1 after the sum.  This was a simplified example to not overcomplicate the question and it looks like I forgot some details!

Comment: @AshleyDuncan As I mentioned, the solution to your problem works in C++17, and all you need to do is write the raw loops instead of the algorithms. I added that solution explicitly in the answer anyway.

Comment: @AshleyDuncan Oh, I see what you mean by the assert being right. Your function was supposed to do `res[res.size()] = cs - 1;` instead of `res[res.size() - 1] = cs;`. Well, that's not relevant to your issue, so it's fine :)

Comment: It think I already know the answer to this, but would it be possible to use a technique like this to initialise a plain array?

Comment: @AshleyDuncan Sure, I think that'll work. Arrays are usable in constexpr contexts IIRC.

Comment: I have been using this for a while now and has been super handy for this project.  Using GCC 8.3 how would one go about compiling the C++ 17 example using line 18 as  `constexpr auto testArray = CheckSummedArray<uint8_t>({1,2,3,4});` (and including stdint.h of course).  It seems that between GCC 8.3 and and 9.3 a change was introduced allowing implicit conversion of int to unsigned char.  Sorry, I am not up to speed on all the language changes.  Obviously each array initialiser element could be cast but I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution?

Comment: @AshleyDuncan I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Could you add a demo (like I linked to in my answer) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sorry, try this one:  https://godbolt.org/z/aPdr5Pjh6

Comment: @AshleyDuncan You could use different template parameters like this https://godbolt.org/z/8jx6e6vnn , i.e. one for the returned array type, and one for the brace initializer list argument.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses.  I don't think I have ever seen template use like that before.  So this would defer the type conversion to the line `res[j] = i[j];`?  I wonder why that doesn't error?  Thanks for your help, I have little experience with templates beyond the simplest application.  Interestingly with this extra template parameter, there is no narrowing conversion warning if the init values are > 256 whereas with the single template parameter there is.  C++ confuses me!!!

Comment: @AshleyDuncan Yes, the conversion happens in `res[j] = i[j]`. However, you should get a warning somewhere if the values are too large https://godbolt.org/z/e753T9W6a You can get the warning inside the definition if you like as well. Try playing around with it for some time, and if you can't get it to work, you can post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am not too worried about the warning, just was interested.